# What Type of Attack Does ssl_stapling on; Protect Against on NGINX

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have these two settings in NGINX:

```
ssl_stapling               on;
ssl_stapling_verify        on;
```

This was working before but stopped working after I reinstalled my OS. I'm wondering what could be the issue. Also, in a MITM type scenario, what type of attack does ssl_stapling and ssl_stapling_verify protect against? If there is an attack where it protects against something, what can I do to mitigate the effectiveness of the attack?

Answer (score 1):

SSL stapling means that revocation information about the servers certificate (i.e. OCSP response) are included in the TLS handshake together with the server certificate. It is currently more a traffic optimization in that an additional OCSP request is not needed (which browsers usually don't anyway).

It will be a security feature if the browser insists on getting the OCSP response stapled. In this case it will prevent some MITM from using a revoked certificate for the domain in order to hijack the traffic and simply blocking the OCSP request/response. Browsers often just give up if the OCSP query fails and thus this attack can work. But again - most browsers don't really use OCSP at all anymore but instead use alternative (and even less reliable) mechanism - see [How Do Browsers Handle Revoked SSL/TLS Certificates?](https://www.ssl.com/article/how-do-browsers-handle-revoked-ssl-tls-certificates/).

The requirement for using OCSP stapling might be a property of the certificate itself (OCSP-must-staple extension), i.e. it might result in a failure if you have such a certificate but did not staple the OCSP response.

Answer (score 0):

Certificates have CRL lists that show it has been revoked. stapling is an alternative way to do this. If you enable this I think your certificate issuer has to support this feature too. I've attached a link below that goes over setting it up on nginx.

https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/nginx-enable-ocsp-stapling-on-server.htm

From what i've read on it so far, it doesn't seem like stapling prevents MITM. It just changes the way a certificate is checked if it is valid and not expired or revoked.

https://www.digicert.com/kb/enabling-ocsp-stapling.htm